# Is there a way to send email from browser?

Tags: javascript, email

So recently I have been designing a website. Part of it requires a user to click a button that opens up Outlook (the app) with the email filled in. However, those people who don't have Outlook (or any other mailing app) can't use this. So I am wondering if there is a way to open the same email using the online email apps (eg outlook.com)?

Comment: The `mailto:` link format has been around for many, many decades, and has nothing to do with outlook. Folks click your `<a>` element with mailto URL, and it opens in whatever their email client of choice is, no matter whether they're on desktop or mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `mailto` event, it just opens the default email app. You could set the outlook webapp as default, although it's not very user friendly  IMO:

1. on outlook page, open console and run: `navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://outlook.office365.com/mail/deeplink/compose/?mailtouri=%s","Outlook");`
2. click allow on popup
3. mailto event should now prepopulate a new email on the outlook webapp

Comment: So how do you then add a certain message in it automatically?

Comment: ```
      window.open(`mailto:someemail@address?subject=${subjectMessage}&body=${bodyMessage}`)
```